# How can I split my spatial layer every 250 records?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, splitting

I have a shapefile table with more or less 12000 sectors. I want to use this as a zonal feature layer, however the tool I want to use it with can only handle 255 zones. Therefore I want to divide the shapefile in 1200/155 individual files.

I thought to do it through model builder with the Select (analysis) tool. I created a list of all values (0 - 255 - 510 - etc). I want to run Select with each time using different values of my list in the Expression. I have no clue how to iterate through the values in the expression.

There is probably a better method for doing this.

Comment: Populate new field using divmod (!Fid!,155)[0] . Search site for split by attributes or similar

Comment: Great, this solved my problem !